# Implement chat with minimum http requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io, httprequest

I am making a completely online website using node.js and react and I want to implement a forum in it. While saving the messages in the mongodb database how should I go about it so I don't have to make an http request for every single message as that will be bad economically. The chat will be implemented using socket.io and I interface with the database using mongoose.

Comment: Could you post some of your attempted code? SO is not a code-maker :)

Comment: I am sorry for that. But I don't really want the code though, I would like to know the optimal way to implement this feature theoretically. I read up on google and found ways like using webrtc to save a stream before batch execution of the data in the db so I don't have to make smaller changes to the db. Is this the standard practice and should I use it?